# pattern для input

Tags: регулярные-выражения

мне нужно сделать pattern для input-а, должен приниматься год только в определенном диапазоне, например от 1940 до 2019, как это сделать ? 
регулярки не очень шарю, а без них чет туплю, не могу условие написать, хелпаните пжлст

Comment: Уверены, что регулярка нужна? А вообще вот: `^(19[4-9]\d|20[0-1]\d)$`

Comment: Эта задача плохо решается на регулярках. Написать её можно, но она будет сложная, что-то вроде `(19[4-9][0-9])|(20[0-1][0-9])|(2010)` Диапазон целых чисел проще проверять непосредственно.

Comment: [Генератор регулярок для числовых диапазонов](http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/) - `pattern="(19[4-9][0-9]|20[01][0-9])"`

Comment: четко, спасибо. а непосредственно это как ?))